# How to combine duplicate rows in R?

Tags: r, rscript

I'm using R to create a data frame with several duplicate columns. I'd like to consolidate all of the duplicated columns into a single column. How to do this in R?

Note 1 : When I build dataframes with multiple columns, R adds numbers to the names of the repeated columns by default.

Note 2: I am looking for code that will work with the columns regardless of their order.

**code:**

```
# Create the data frame.
emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25), 
  salary = c(700.3,600.2,721.0,730.5,845.4), 
  emp_name = c("Kevin","Tracy","Thompson","Peter","Bevan"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
# Print the data frame.         
print(emp.data)
```

**current result**

```
         emp_name   salary   salary.1 emp_name.1
         Rick       623.3    700.3    Kevin
         Dan        515.20   600.2    Tracey
         Michelle   611.00   721.0    Thompson
         Ryan       729.00   730.5    Peter
         Gary       843.25   845.4    Bevan
```

**Expected output**

```
       emp_name   salary   
         Rick       623.3    
         Dan        515.20   
         Michelle   611.00   
         Ryan       729.00   
         Gary       843.25   
         Kevin      700.3
         Tracey     600.2
         Thompson   721.0
         Peter      730.5
         Bevan      845.4
```

Comment: DO you have a good reason to not write the salary column like that: salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25, 700.3,600.2,721.0,730.5,845.4)?

Comment: @glagla, could you elaborate more on your question?

Comment: In your real dataframe do you have columns with same name or you have `.1` or `.2` as suffix added in them ?

Comment: @glagla Gotta be some specs of OP's real datasets yet I don't see any reason to store data that way.

Comment: @RonakShah, I don't have the suffixes in the real data frame, therefore I've written a note about it in 'Note 1' above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(emp.data), measure = patterns("^emp_name", "salary"),
     value.name = c("emp_name", "salary"))[, variable := NULL][]
    emp_name salary
 1:     Rick 623.30
 2:      Dan 515.20
 3: Michelle 611.00
 4:     Ryan 729.00
 5:     Gary 843.25
 6:    Kevin 700.30
 7:    Tracy 600.20
 8: Thompson 721.00
 9:    Peter 730.50
10:    Bevan 845.40
```

#### data

```
emp.data <- structure(list(emp_name = c("Rick", "Dan", "Michelle", "Ryan", 
"Gary"), salary = c(623.3, 515.2, 611, 729, 843.25), salary = c(700.3, 
600.2, 721, 730.5, 845.4), emp_name = c("Kevin", "Tracy", "Thompson", 
"Peter", "Bevan")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `split.default` to split data into list of dataframes based on it's column names. `unlist` each dataframe into vector and then you can create a single column from it.

```
data.frame(lapply(split.default(emp.data, names(emp.data)), unlist), row.names = NULL)

#   emp_name salary
#1      Rick 623.30
#2       Dan 515.20
#3  Michelle 611.00
#4      Ryan 729.00
#5      Gary 843.25
#6     Kevin 700.30
#7     Tracy 600.20
#8  Thompson 721.00
#9     Peter 730.50
#10    Bevan 845.40
```

---

Another option using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` -

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(emp.data, cols = everything(), names_to = '.value')
```

**data**

To create dataframe with the same column names you can add `check.names = FALSE` in `data.frame` call.

```
emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25), 
  salary = c(700.3,600.2,721.0,730.5,845.4), 
  emp_name = c("Kevin","Tracy","Thompson","Peter","Bevan"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Yes it works perfectly as expected. Thank you for the expected solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge fan of this solution but it works and should scale.

```
emp.data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("emp_name"), names_to = "ename", values_to = "emp_name") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("salary"), names_to = "sname", values_to  = "salary") %>%
  filter(replace_na(parse_number(ename),0) == replace_na(parse_number(sname), 0)) %>%
  select(-ename, -sname)
```

NB requires `tidyr` for `parse_number`

Comment: Thank you, but I am expecting the solution without hardcoding the column names.